# How to heapify the minheap using an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

This program should work correctly but it doesn't! assume you are building a minheap by inserting nmubers into an array. Each time of insertion should be followed by Heapify function to make sure that the sort of numbers do not violate the minheap rule. This is what I wrote but there is something wrong with it and I couldn't make it!

```
int P(int i) //returning the index of parent
{

    if (i % 2 == 0) { i = ((i - 2) / 2); }
    else { i = ((i - 1) / 2); }
    return i;
}

void Heapify(double A[], int i)//putting the smallest value in the root because we have a min heap
{
    if (P(i) != NULL && A[i] < A[P(i)])
    {
        temp = A[P(i)];
        A[P(i)] = A[i];
        A[i] = temp;
        Heapify(A, P(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know there is something wrong with it?

Comment: unless you are doing this for academic reasons, you can just use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/

Comment: `P(i) != NULL`? I think you translated this directly from Java or something like that?

Comment: @Manu343726 There is nothing similar to that that would be valid in Java.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in this that isn't just plain ol' *C*.

Comment: At the top of my coding, I defined array A as NULL so if nothing is inserted in a given A[i], it should be NULL. Correct me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, your heapify function doesn't seem to take a minimum of both left and right branches into consideration. Let me show you an ideal, working implementation (object-oriented, so you might want to pass the heap as a parameter). You can find the exact pseudocode all over the internet, so I'm not really presenting anything unique.

```
void Heap::Heapify (int i)
{
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    int lowest;

    if (l < heap_size && heap[l] -> value < heap[i] -> value )
        lowest = l;
    else
        lowest = i;
    if (r < heap_size && heap[r] -> value < heap[lowest] -> value)
        lowest = r;
    if (lowest != i)
    {
        swap (heap[i], heap[lowest]);
        Heapify(lowest);
    }
}
```

where

```
int left    ( int i ) { return 2 * i; }
int right   ( int i ) { return 2 * i + 1; }
```

As you can see, an algorithm first checks which one of left and right children have lower value. That value is swapped with current value. That is everything there is to it.

Comment: I don't know if doing his homework for him is the best answer.

Comment: @JasonC While I do realize this, I feel like heapify is such a common algorithm that it's nothing that one has to re-invent over an over.